# I need to audit my SQL Db to see how much data is collected

Tags: sql-server, query

I am looking to audit my SQL DB inside audit logs in azure to see how much data is collected when running a query so that way I can calculate how much it costs me but I cant seem to find the right query to run to generate that

Comment: You pay for two things in Azure SQL DB, storage of your data and a maximum number of available DTU's.  I don't think you can find a $/query value.  Instead you should look for the queries that are the most expensive to run (or run most often).  I would suggest starting with queries that consume the most logical page reads or take the longest.